# X is not a member type of Y

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm having staring issues with Module name spacing in a swift project.

I've tried this in a new project and everything works fine:

I have 2 modules with which contain the same class name and i'm able to reference the class from `Module.Class` no problem.

I have an existing swift project and I'm unable to get this working.  I keep getting the error

[image]

So as you can see if I don't try to *Module-Scope* the class everything works fine.

(And yes i've tried with and with out the `.Type` addition).

So I'm assuming there is something off in my compiler setting.  The only other thing I can think of is that my LocationMessage class is defined not in the main DataManager "class" file but rather in a different file.

But I really can't make heads or tails of whats going on.  Any suggestions?

#### Project Structure

**Framework: DataManager**

- DataManager.swift
- LocationMessages.swift

**Framework: ReferenceTest**

- File.swift

So my issue is that in `File.swift` I'm trying to reference a class defined in `LocationMessages.swift` inside the `DataManager.framework`  The class **IS** public

```
@objc(DMLocationMessage)
final public class LocationMessage : ParsedMessage {
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a `class/struct/enum DataManager` anywhere in your code which hides the `DataManager` module? The error states that it cannot find `LocationManager` in **type** `DataManager` where it should read **module** instead.

Comment: I do have a class called DataManager!

Comment: ugh... thats going to be a LOT of changes to make...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You likely have a `class/struct/enum DataManager` anywhere in your code which hides the `DataManager` module. The error states that it cannot find `LocationManager` in **type** `DataManager` where it should read **module** instead.

Your app modules should be designed in a way so that you never need to explicitly use the module's name except for the `import` statement. So just use `LocationMessage.Type` directly without stating the module.

This is one reason **all** our app's modules are prefixed with an `X`, e.g. `XDataManager`. This avoids conflicts with Apple's modules, external modules (like from CocoaPods) and with types (like in your case).
The `X` also makes it obvious that these modules are part of the app itself and not some third-party frameworks.

Comment: I tried to move away from the old OBJC style Naming prefix - ala swift although i do use @objc(DMXXXX) prefix at times.  Perhaps its time to bring it back.

Comment: We also removed all our prefixes but until Swift supports submodules we opted to maintain a prefix for app modules.

Answer (score 24):

There is also this bug in swift compiler: [SR-631 Extensions in different files do not recognize each other](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-631)

The result (success/failure) of the compilation depends on the order of files in *Build Phase > Compile Sources* setting.

I had exactly the same error message: *X is not a member type of Y*. Solved it by rearranging compilation sources.

Comment: Thank you! This saved my evening :)

Comment: @Anton you're my hero. Seriously — I was losing my mind and you just kept me sane.

Comment: If you're using Swift `2.0`, `3.1` or `4.1`: put the file that defines the enum at the top of you _Build Phase > Compile Sources_ settings.

Comment: Brilliant! Changing build order solved my problem. Thanks :)

Comment: Awesome! Just got bitten by this.

Answer (score 17):

In case anyone is here while trying to build and use an xcframework, apparently, the issue is caused when you have a class in the framework which has the same name as the module/framework.

This is a known issue and needs a workaround as mentioned [here](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123253).

P.S. - I know this doesn't answer this question per se. Just leaving it here for anyone else who might land here because of the question title.

Answer (score 11):

If using **xcframework** follow below steps to get rid of error :

1. In terminal, go to the folder where .xcframework is located.
2. Run the following terminal command after replacing the **frameworkName** with your framework name:

> find . -name "*.swiftinterface" -exec sed -i -e
>   's/frameworkName\.//g' {} \;

3. Replace the old xcframework in your project with xcframework generated with above command. Clean build the project.

The above error only occurs in xcframework when a class named is same as the module name. Details on Apple forum at: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/123253

Answer (score 2):

When using an **xcframework** that depends on another framework, the `X is not a member of type Y` will also happen for the Framework it depends on when writing an extensions that wraps, for example, delegate methods

Example:
Framework Foo depends on Bar and need to conform to DataDelegate.

```
class Foo {
    ...
}

extension Foo : Bar.DataDelegate {
    ...
}
```

Everything during compiling will go as planned and the xcframework will be generated. Once you add it to your App along with the dependancy framework Bar and try to build it you will get `DataDelegate is not a member of type Bar`.

Comment: this is the issue i am having. i played around with the generated .swiftinterface files and deleted the "Class." prefix from all those files and it works. is this the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this!

You should

1. Create a new empty swift file
2. Import just the type (not entire module) you need to use:

```
/* import MyModule */ // NOT THIS!

import enum MyModule.Theme // This will only import the `enum`.  You can use this method for `class`, `structs` and others too.
```

3. Make a `typealias` for the imported type:

```
typealias MyUniqueName = MyModule.Theme
```

4. Use the new unique name that you just created.

This is the only workaround  that compiler understand  what do you mean exactly (without need to change the internal module names.

---

## Result

Remember the final file will contain only two lines:

```
import enum MyModule.Theme
typealias MyUniqueName = MyModule.Theme
```